# React, why are my private routes rendered for a brief second to unauthorized users before the redirect kicks in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been using private routes in order to secure them, but the problem im facing is that whenever an unauthorized user enters that route, he will be able to see the protected route content for a brief second, right before he is redirected again to a default route for unauthorized users.

Why is that happening? I suspect that it happens because my auth verification service relies on an external server, and that causes a delay on the verification, while the user is being verified it happens to display the protected route, but once it has finished verifying it and the result is "unauthorized" it redirects the user to another unprotected route.

This is how my PrivateRoute looks

```
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, ...rest }) =>
  Component ? (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authed === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => authed === true ? renderFn(props) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} /> } /> 
    );
```

This is my router, localted in app.js

```
    <BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path='/register' component={RegisterPage} />
    <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <LoginPage />} />
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <NewLandingPage {...props} />} />
    <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/route1" render={props => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.route1} className="iframe" />} />
    <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/route2" render={props => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.route2} className="iframe" />} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is the constructor of my app.js

```
  this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: true 
        }
```

And this is what I have in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    isAuthenticated().then((result) => {
        if (result == true) {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false})
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see its making a call to an authentication server, and I suspect that its where the delay happens and that might be the cause of the render happening to unauthorized users

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function isAuthenticated() {
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

    return axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3003/verify', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accesstoken}` } })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status === "valid") {
                console.log("service valid")
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("service invalid")
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

How can I solve this? I was thinking about adding a middle page in the PrivateRoute with "loading" content, or something like that, but im not sure how or where to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of please use strict null checks (i.e.: myBool === true) because they protect you from referencing nulls or undefined values in code.

For your problem it looks like  that isAuthenticated is always true in the beginning. Axios async response then automatically changes that value afterwards.

In your app.js you already initialise isAuthenticated value to true, try setting it to false in the beginning since i guess that all your users should not be authenticated in the beginning right?

Everything else looks fine for me.

Comment: You are right, the issue was with the default true, changed it to false, and it works fine now